# Validate prefilled form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Good day. On the beginning I would like to apologize for the big mess in the last part of code. I have a problem with validating my pre-filled form. So what I have done so far is a form with pre-filled values. When user clicks on the field it removes pre-filled value. 
I was trying to validate this form against empty fields, but as long as they are pre-filled it doesn't show there is a missing string.

Let me present the HTML:

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="form1" class="form" action="scripts/form-quote.php">
    <input class="swap validate"     id="name"      name="name"         type="text" value="Name" />                                             <p id="iname" class="validation-error"></p>
    <input class="swap emailvalid"   id="email"     name="email"        type="text" value="E-mail" />                                           <p id="iemail" class="validation-error"></p>
    <textarea class="swap validate" id="add-req" name="add-req" cols="43" rows="8" >Please explain your requirements</textarea>                 <p id="iadd-req" class="validation-error"></p>
    <input class="swap"  id="ad"        name="ad"           type="text" value="Where did you hear about us?" />

    <input class="submit" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

and jQuery - this part is working OK:

```
    $.fn.swapText = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var tmpDefVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).css('color', '#999');

        $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == tmpDefVal){
                $(this)
                    .css('color', '#000')
                    .val('');
            }
        });

        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this)
                    .css('color', '#999')
                    .val(tmpDefVal);
            }
        });

    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.swap').swapText();

});
```

jQuery - this is a complete mess. I was trying to recreate the existing one which I've done a long time ago with some help, but it was validating against the empty fields. Now I want to validate it against the prefilled fields:

```
    function isNotEmpty(string){

    if(string.length < 1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function checkOnChange(){
    var infoField = document.getElementById('i'+this.id);

    if(this.type == 'checkbox'){ 
        if(this.checked){
            infoField.innerHTML = '';
        }else{
            infoField.innerHTML = 'Required field';
        }
    }else{
        if(isNotEmpty(this.value)){
            this.className = 'ok';
            infoField.innerHTML = '';
            //this.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }else{
            //this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            this.className = 'err';
            infoField.innerHTML = 'Required field';
        }
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.swap').swapText();
    $('#email').swapText();

    $('#email').keyup(function(){
        var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if(regexp.test($(this).val())){
            $(this).removeClass('err');
            $(this).addClass('ok');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('ok');
            $(this).addClass('err');
        }
    });
});


window.onload = function(){

    var inputName = document.getElementById('name');
    var inputMsg = document.getElementById('add-req');

    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
        var formValid = true;

        if(isNaN(this.nrklienta.value)){
        }else{
        }

        if(!isNotEmpty(this.pers.value)){
            var infoField = document.getElementById('i'+this.pers.id);

            this.pers.className = 'err';
            infoField.innerHTML = 'Required field';

            formValid = false;
        }else{
        }

        //return false;
        if(formValid){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


}





//* Email validation

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#email').swapText();

    $('#email').keyup(function(){
        var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if(regexp.test($(this).val())){
            $(this).removeClass('err');
            $(this).addClass('ok');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('ok');
            $(this).addClass('err');
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for the big mess in the last part of code, but this is just to show what I'm trying to achieve.
So if the user won't fill the #name, #email (validation code for email should be working, no idea why it doesn't) and #add-req (or better if it can be done by class .validate) then after clicking Send button it will not send a form but display a message in p (.validation-error) "Required field" + change class of the actual field.

The jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/Wq7qE/)

Comment: Use the `placeholder` attribute instead of pre-filling.

Comment: put your input hint in `placeholder` attribute if you are targeting advance browsers

Comment: unfortunately placeholder works similar to prefilled input, so it's not ignored by validator and returns a value @Barmar , thanks anyway

Comment: @muneebShabbir as above - the same result - it returns a value, so its ignored by validator

Comment: Are you using real placeholders, or a plugin that simulates them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a prefilled value, you should be using the `<label>` element for each `<input>` and the `placeholder` attribute.

For example, just taking one of your inputs, you could use:

```
<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input class="swap emailvalid" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
```

You can hide the label with CSS if you don't want it displayed, but it should still be present for non-sighted users.

You will find that using a placeholder will spare you from jumping through all sorts of hoops in your code to achieve the desired result.  Allow me to [demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Wq7qE/8/). (If jsfiddle.net is still down, use http://jsbin.com/akesep/2/edit.)

Use the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="scripts/form-quote.php">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="required" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
            <input class="required" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="add-req">Message</label>
            <textarea class="required" id="add-req" name="add-req" cols="43" rows="8" placeholder="Please enter your message"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="ad">Referrer</label>
            <input id="ad" name="ad" type="text" placeholder="Where did you hear about us?" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Nice and clean markup.  No prefilled values to complicate the javascript. Placeholders and labels used properly.

Then the following jQuery script will validate for completion of required fields and valid email:

```
var addErrorMessage = function (field) {
        var err = $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('validation-error').text('Required field');
        field.addClass('err').after(err);
    },
    clearError = function () {
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.hasClass('err')) {
            t.removeClass('err');
            t.next('p').empty().remove();
        }
    },
    isEmpty = function (str) {
        return str.trim().length < 1;
    },
    isValidEmail = function (str) {
        var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        return regexp.test(str);
    },
    validateForm = function () {
        var requiredFields = $(this).find('.required'),
            email = $('#email'),
            fieldsValidate = true;

        // check that required fields are not empty
        requiredFields.each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            if (isEmpty(t.val())) {
                fieldsValidate = false;
                if (!t.hasClass('err')) {
                    addErrorMessage(t);
                }
            }
        });

        // check that email is valid
        if (!isValidEmail(email.val().trim())) {
            fieldsValidate = false;
            if (!email.hasClass('err')) {
                addErrorMessage(email);
            }
        }

        return fieldsValidate;
    };

$('input, textarea').keyup(clearError);
$('#form1').submit(validateForm);
```

You can easily add other types of validation as well following the same principles, but this should give you a good start.

Comment: thank you, never done that before, I would kindly appreciate any sort of code modification, so I can try it.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski, I've given you an example in my answer.  Do you need more than that?

Comment: Actually it will be very helpful. I have spent a lot of time figuring out the swap text function in jquery. I will definitely have difficulties with implementing this. Ideally (I know it's not fair) would be get a whole fixed code so I can analize it and learn from it how to do this in future. I do understand quite a bit, but writting it from scratch is quite difficult on my level of jQuery knowledge

Comment: jsFiddle is a perfect tool which helps a lot. I have put the whole code in jsfiddle, as in a question

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski, it might take a while, as your code is a mess.  Are you only validating for empty fields right now?

Comment: yes, that was the original code i wrote some time ago. I know its a mess. I have no idea how to clean it to make it look better. Thank you for your effort @DerekHenderson

Comment: unfortunately placeholder works similar to prefilled input, so it's not ignored by validator and returns a value. :(

Comment: No, it works perfectly.  Apologies it has taken so long, but jsfiddle is veeeerrrryyy slow right now.  I have created a working example for you at http://jsbin.com/akesep/1/edit.  When jsfiddle starts working again, I'll post that as well.

Comment: thank you @DerekHenderson I will take a look on it immediately.

Comment: thanks it looks great. I have found one issue - when you click Send couple of times it keeps generating the .validation-error. Is this easy to alter?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have fixed that but was getting frustrated with the jsfiddle problems. I don't mind fixing this, but I've already spent a lot of time on this, so I would be happy if you upvoted and accepted my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Of course. I've accepted your answer. I've upvoted it already. ALso there is a fragment of code (the very last part) of email verification. It has been working on its own, as I used it previously. Unfortunately it doesn't in this case. Is it a quick job to add it to the code you provided and verify is email correctly typed in? so including sth + @ + sth + . + sth ? Thank you very much. You already helped me a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: I made two improvements to the code.  The error message is no longer repeated, and the string is trimmed when checking if it's empty.

Comment: I have a question - is label necessary? you hidden it anyway. or is it for SEO purposes?

Comment: It's a requirement for accessibility. If you don't want them displayed, hide them as I have, but you should always have them.

Comment: And the email validation now works as well. I hope this is enough that you can add any other validation you require on your own. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32969/discussion-between-piotr-ciszewski-and-derek-henderson)